# update some field on mongodb not all. How?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm still learning about Node.js & MongoDB so my question is:
on Update functionality would like to update some of the fields not necessary all on them So How i can do that ?

**Note:** i used the same validateTask function for insert new data to tasks document.

```js
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {

    const { error } = validateTask(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            name: req.body.name,
            employee: req.body.employee,
            description: req.body.description,
            section: req.body.section,
            status: req.body.status,
            updated_at: new Date()
    }, { new: true })
    .then ( data => {
        res.status(201).send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(422).send('The task with given ID was not found');
    });

});



function validateTask(task) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        employee: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        description: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        section: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
        status: Joi.boolean()
    };

    return Joi.validate(task, schema);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what is the problem here. findByIdAndUpdate will update only the fields specified

Comment: Adding to the above comment, the only fields updated are the ones that have changed

Comment: maybe because validateTask function which set some field as require and i have to create another validateTask with no require for update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the validateTask validation**

The error is because in validateTask function you have made all the fields as required and these paramters are validated  before findByIdAndUpdate.

I believe You need not have any required(mandatory field) validation to be done in update. This validation can be only done for documents that are newly inserted

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can use Task.findByIdAndUpdate it will only update the fields you give to for example

```
User: {
  name: Ahmed Gamal
  email: ahmed@ahmedgamal.ga
  country: Egypt 
}
```

When used with findByIdAndUpdate and given `{name: Ahmed}` the result will be

```
User: {
  name: Ahmed
  email: ahmed@ahmedgamal.ga
  country: Egypt 
}
```

Comment: Currently my code works find on update but i have to set all field before send the data otherwise it will display an error some field required so my question: Do i need to make another validate function for an update separate from validate function for creation ?